# Issues when using xe:formTable and Bootstrap theme in Extension Library

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, github, xpages, xpages-extlib

I was going to report this to IBM (GitHub) but need to know if I am doing something wrong here.

I am using the latest version of ExtLib v9.0.1v00_11
I have created an empty database, enabled the bootstrap theme and use the following code which creates a form table with a label and a field

```
<xe:formTable id="formTable1">
    <xe:formRow id="formRow1" label="Name">
        <xe:formColumn id="formColumn1">
            <xp:inputText id="inputText1"></xp:inputText>
        </xe:formColumn>
    </xe:formRow>
</xe:formTable>
```

In the image below everything looks right, there is a nice grey background and the html fieldset is mapped to a dbootstrap class. I have enabled the "Use runtime optimized JS and CSS resources"

[image]

In the image below I have I the same code but have disabled the "Use runtime optimized JS and CSS resources" and now there is no grey background and the reference to the dbootstrap class is missing

[image]

I did try to add the formtable into a application layout control but I got the same result.
One strange thing is that When I try out the ONEUI_Form xpage in the Extlib sample database I cannot reproduce the problem.

Is this a bug in extlib or what am I doing wrong as it seem to work in the extlib sample db?
I am not getting any errors in the browser debug console, I have also tried to change the HTML doc type to HTML5 or HTML strict but that did not help

Comment: There seems to be other issues as well: if you activate resource aggregation the icons disappear like they did when using an external theme... I'd strongly recommend using the BS4XSP plugin and create your own layout stuff and form controls.

Comment: Looks like a bug to be honest. The team will be back in the office on Monday, I'll raise this issue and we'll investigate

Comment: Thanks Brian. Appreciate it